# Register local notification from background

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, geolocation, notifications, uilocalnotification

I have a situation where I have to present alert while my app is in background.
So I was thinking that the solution is Local notification. 
But the problem is that, I want to show that alert only when user has crossed a particular predefined location point.

So I have to show the notification without any registration for it in Foreground(Or you can say register the local notification in background).

Is it doable ?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can let your run in the background while you still receive location updates.

You have to the add [`location`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22) to [`UIBackgroundModes`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html) in your apps `info.plist`;

And any instance of [CLLocationManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125) will keep receiving location updates.
But be aware that this could drain the battery of the iPhone really fast, so it's a good idea to only monitor major location changes.

Comment: Thanks, But My question was related to register the Notification. can you give some light towards that ?

Comment: You can just create the [`UILocalNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and schedule the notification like you normally would. If the [`fireDate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009565-CH1-SW2) is the current time the notification will be displayed immediately.

Comment: Oh great then let me try that.